# Eclipse Indigo with Scala and play framework?

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo

I am getting error in Eclipse:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Scala Search 0.2.4.v-2_11-201503032143-77c20d5 (org.scala.tools.eclipse.search.feature.feature.group 0.2.4.v-2_11-201503032143-77c20d5)
Missing requirement: Scala Plugin 4.0.0.v-2_11-201412161058-027320c (org.scala-ide.sdt.core 4.0.0.v-2_11-201412161058-027320c) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core [3.10.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
Missing requirement: Scala Plugin 4.0.0.v-2_11-201501121809-027320c (org.scala-ide.sdt.core 4.0.0.v-2_11-201501121809-027320c) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core [3.10.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
Missing requirement: Scala Plugin 4.0.0.v-2_11-201503031937-b2bbad6 (org.scala-ide.sdt.core 4.0.0.v-2_11-201503031937-b2bbad6) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core [3.10.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: Scala Search 0.2.4.v-2_11-201503032143-77c20d5 (org.scala.tools.eclipse.search 0.2.4.v-2_11-201503032143-77c20d5)
  To: bundle org.scala-ide.sdt.core [4.0.0,5.0.0)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: Scala Search 0.2.4.v-2_11-201503032143-77c20d5 (org.scala.tools.eclipse.search.feature.feature.group 0.2.4.v-2_11-201503032143-77c20d5)
  To: org.scala.tools.eclipse.search [0.2.4.v-2_11-201503032143-77c20d5]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among other things this is telling you that 'Scala Search' requires version 3.10 (or later) of the 'org.eclipse.jdt.core' plugin. This version of the plugin is in Eclipe 4.4 (Luna) so you need to be using Luna to install this.

Comment: you are right sir , but i have some problem in luna my code is running in luna without error but scala compiler is null error are coming in that , i am facing this problem last two days , please suggest me how can i setup properly playframe work with scala

Comment: i think there is some versions problem now i have stuck in this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Scala - I just know how to read the install errors.